# How i can link my domain to my Heroku app?

Tags: heroku, dns, custom-domain

I have free domain from freenom.com. I create custom domain in app settings on Heroku and setup given me 'DNS target' on my domain DNS settings on Freenom. But even after several days, website not accessible via my domain. What am I doing wrong?

Domain from freenom.com:

[image]

Custom domains on Heroku:

[image]

DNS settings on Freenom:

[image]

Website doesn't work:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't DNS issue.

The browser error message shows that you are trying to access the site over HTTPS (not HTTP), and is displaying an SSL error. Have you set up a certificate for your custom domain, e.g. via [Automated Certificate Management](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management) (ACM)?

Modern browsers often default to HTTPS, and it even looks like you have set up a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS. You'll need a certificate to make that work. ACM, as noted above, is the simplest solution but it does require that you are using a paid dyno on Heroku.

You can also [bring your own certificate](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl#manually-upload-certificates) if you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

You should add an A-record for your domain[1] pointing to your website's server IP address on freenom's DNS management page.

[1] urlcuter.tk